# How to add endpoint to wso2 esb rest api from config.properties file?

Tags: esb, wso2-esb

I have a REST Service which need calls RestService on wso2 ESB and RestService. It needs to send REST request (POST) to another REST service. But RestService on ESB needs to get URL and add user/password from property file and add to Header(user/password) and send request to URL of another rest service.

Example: REST call ESB RestAPI, RestAPI get URL, user/password from property file and send POST request to REST Service to got URL from property.

Comment: And all services send and get data in json fromat.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/retrieve-values-xml-config)on how to Retrieve Values From XML in Config Registry with WSO2 ESB.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816328/how-to-set-different-authorization-header-for-different-endpoint-in-wso2-esb) on how to set an authorization header for the endpoint.